# FFI error module not found

Tags: linux, smalltalk, ffi, pharo

I'm using Ubuntu 64bit and Pharo 1.2.1

I've written some FFI code that accesses crypt(3) from glibc.  I'd like to change it to access crypt from libxcrypt that I install using apt-get.  When I change the method from:

```
ffiCrypt: aKey with: aSalt
<cdecl: char* 'crypt' (char* char*) module: 'crypt'>
^self externalCallFailed
```

to:

```
ffiCrypt: aKey with: aSalt
<cdecl: char* 'crypt' (char* char*) module: '/lib/libxcrypt.so.1'>
^self externalCallFailed
```

I get External Module Not Found errors.  I've linked to the libxcrypt.so.1 file from the directory my image is in.

I suspect it could be a 64 bit vs 32 bit library thing or that I need to link the library somewhere else but do not know.

What are some steps or things I could check to try to track down why the external module cannot be found?

Comment: If you answer your own question, I'd sure people would be more than happy to upvote your (presumably correct!) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was both a 64bit vs 32bit library issue and a linking issue.

Reading this:

http://forum.world.st/FFI-library-dependency-howto-td50461.html#a50462

helped me learn about where Pharo looks for libraries so I just had to install the 32 bit libxcrypt and link to it properly.